# JavaFx 2 - Setting Pane with fxml dynamically

Tags: javafx-2

I am trying to set center pane of border pane layout dynamically by loading from fxml file. Right now, I am encountering null pointer exception when I invoke setCenterPane() method. Below is the controller code that load and set center pane. The type of pane that I am trying to load is AnchorPane, and I have tried to cast it to AnchorPane too, but it still behaves the same. I am not sure if I am missing something. Could anyone provide any idea on how to solve this issue?

The null pointer exception is throwing form ***borderPane.setCenter(cmdPane)*** line. (I remove some lines form my code for readability).

```
public class AnalyzerController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private BorderPane borderPane;

@FXML
private void cmdMenuAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("CommandQuery.fxml"));
        Pane cmdPane = (Pane) fxmlLoader.load();

        try {
            borderPane.setCenter(cmdPane);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

}

Below is the exception trace.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at analyzer.AnalyzerController.cmdMenuAction(AnalyzerController.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:269)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1435)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:28)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:6863)
    at javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink.fire(Hyperlink.java:145)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:193)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:336)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:64)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3328)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3168)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3123)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1563)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2265)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:250)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:173)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:292)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:528)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:922)
```

This is Analyzer.fxml referenced by AnalyzerController

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>

<BorderPane id="BorderPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="analyzer.AnalyzerController">
  <center>
    <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
      <children>
        <Label fx:id="noDbLabel" layoutX="187.0" layoutY="99.0" text="No database selected." />
      </children>
    </Pane>
  </center>
  <left>
    <Hyperlink fx:id="cmdMenu" onAction="#cmdMenuAction" text="Command" />
  </left>
  <top>
    <MenuBar>
      <menus>
        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
          <items>
            <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openDbAction" text="Open Database" fx:id="OpenDb" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
      </menus>
    </MenuBar>
  </top>
</BorderPane>
```

Here is CommandQuery.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.collections.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" styleClass="mainFxmlClass" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="analyzer.CommandQueryController">
  <children>
    <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.29396984924623115" focusTraversable="true" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
      <items>
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
          <children>
            <Label layoutX="36.0" layoutY="23.0" text="Find" />
            <ComboBox fx:id="cmdTypeBox" layoutX="78.0" layoutY="23.0">
              <items>
                <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                  <String fx:value="Item 1" />
                  <String fx:value="Item 2" />
                  <String fx:value="Item 3" />
                </FXCollections>
              </items>
            </ComboBox>
            <Label layoutX="177.0" layoutY="23.0" text="From" />
          </children>
        </AnchorPane>
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0" />
      </items>
    </SplitPane>
  </children>
  <stylesheets>
    <URL value="@commandquery.css" />
  </stylesheets>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: can you post the `CommandQuery.fxml` and the `fxml` file refenced from `AnalyzerController` ?

Comment: also what's on line `AnalyzerController.java:65`

Comment: I have included CommandQuery.fxml in my question. @SergeyGrinev the exception is throwing form borderPane.setCenter(cmdPane) line. I removed some lines form my code for readability.

Comment: In your FXML `<BorderPane id="BorderPane"...>` shouldn't that be borderPane with small b (same as `private BorderPane borderPane` in your controller)?

Comment: Yes, indeed! A silly typo mistake from refactoring at 2 am! Thanks a lot @Perneel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to call a method on `borderPane` but `borderPane` is never initialized. The `@FXML` tag tells me that you expected `borderPane` to be initialized when you loaded `Analyzer.fxml`. If that's the case, then you need to add `fx:id="borderPane"` to your `Analyzer.fxml` file.